# How to get eloquent data which was created before mode itself

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have two tables (products and product_bids). While getting product_bids i need to attach the products which were created before the bid itself.

Here's my code:

```
$query = ProductBid::whereStatus(ProductBid::STATUS_ACTIVE)->whereNot('user_id', Auth::id());

$query->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
        $q->whereIn('code', Product::whereUserId(Auth::id())->select('code')->get())
             ->whereStatus(Product::STATUS_ACTIVE);
        });`
```

In this case how can I write a condition to take the products which were created before the product_bid. (products.created_at < product_bids.created_at). I can't find a way to write this in query builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = ProductBid::whereStatus(ProductBid::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    ->whereNot('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->whereHas('product', static function (Builder $q): void {
        $q->whereColumn('products.created_at', '<', 'product_bids.created_at')
            ->whereIn('code', Product::whereUserId(Auth::id())->pluck('code'))
            ->whereStatus(Product::STATUS_ACTIVE);
    })->get();
```